# Web API encoding issue causing http 500 code

Tags: asp.net-web-api, telerik, .net-2.0

I am currently working on a .net 2.0 Web forms application. At one point, it is making a call to a web api:

http://webservice/method?key=value

it is passing the webservice call as:

http://webservice/method%0fkey%0dvalue

The web dev tools (f12) state that there is no parameter (value) and that http://webservice/method?key=value is not a valid virtual path.

I am running this locally on iis (windows 10). Why would the ? and = become encoded like this? I am out of ideas on how to debug this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code where you call the web api? Seems like a encoding/decoding issue

Comment: Let me see what I can do. I'll get something up in a bit. @matthijsb